# Цикл - Перебор - Клик

Tags: javascript

Следующий код всегда выдает последний результат, то есть 2 (длина массива `h`):

```
var h = document.getElementsByClassName('h');
// h.length = 2

for(var i = 0; i < h.length; i++){
    h[i].onclick = function(){
       console.log(i) // выдает последний результат, то есть 2...
    }
}
```

Как получить `i`, на котором произошел клик?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это известная особенность JavaScript. Определяя функцию в цикле, вы тем самым создаете замыкание, использующее переменную `i`. Проблема в том, что используется именно переменная, а не ее текущее значение.

Решение этой проблемы, работающее в ES3+, имеет вид:

```
var h = document.getElementsByClassName('h');

for(var i = 0; i < h.length; i++){
    h[i].onclick = (function(index) {
        return function(){
            alert(index);
        };
    })(i);
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b0bn8mfa/

Comment: Добавлю, что промежуточную функцию лучше вынести из цикла.

Answer (score 1):

Подложить что ли свинью?

```js
'use strict';

var h = document.getElementsByClassName('h');

for(let i = 0; i < h.length; i++) {
    h[i].onclick = function() {
       console.log(i);
    }
}
```

```html
<button class=h>1</button>
<button class=h>2</button>
<button class=h>3</button>
```

А вообще, прочитай про то, как работает замыкание и какая область видимости у переменной: http://learn.javascript.ru/functions-closures

Comment: Стоит упомянуть, что это решение будет работать только в ES6+.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, фраза "Подложить что ли свинью?" как бы намекает, что с этим решением что-то не то :) Там даже use strict неспроста написан.