# Помогите разобраться с циклом for

Tags: javascript

Добрый день, я написал небольшой код, который должен нажать на ссылку, сделать определенное действие, закрыть, и выполнить эти же действия снова.

```
var i;
for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  var sec = 5; // Сколько секунд // Таймер
  var a = setInterval(function () {
    sec--;
    if (sec == 0) {
      $("#slide" + i).click();
      clearInterval(a);
      clearInterval(a);
    };
  }, 1000);
  var b22 = 6;// Сколько секунд // Таймер
  var a = setInterval(function () {
    b22--;
    if (b22 == 0) {
      $("#mail_box_editable").html("С Днем рождения тебя!");
      $("#mail_box_send").click();
      clearInterval(a);
    };
  }, 1000);
}
```

Здесь два таймера, с интервалом 5 и 6 секунд. Один отвечает за нажатия на ссылку, второй за отправку сообщения. Но почему-то код не хочет работать с циклом, а иногда и срабатывает. Код вставляю в консоль, ошибок не выдает, и по этому я не могу решить проблему самостоятельно.

Comment: у вас код очень плохо оформлен и поэтому в нем сложно разбираться.

Comment: Посмотрите здесь, там более подписанный. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/651567/revisions

Comment: Там всего два таймера, в который выполняется код. Над таймерами я установил цикл, и закрыл цикл в конце кода.

Comment: я вам как раз его и переформатировал, что было хоть как-то понятно. у вас там проблемы с замыканием.

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста здесь https://jsfiddle.net/bopnfw4b/2/ Я хочу чтобы цикл сам заполнил текстом каждый див с классом a1-a6.

Comment: Возможно найдете для себя что-нибудь полезное http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/446289/182771

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужны не циклы, а рекурсия (с учетом асинхронной природы JavaScript). Вот пример того, как можно решить вашу задачу:

```
var run = function (start, limit) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#slide" + start).click();
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#mail_box_editable").html("С Днем рождения тебя!");
            $("#mail_box_send").click();
            if (start < limit) {
                run(start + 1, limit);
            }
        }, 6 * 1000);
    }, 5 * 1000);
};

run(0, 12);
```

Comment: Класс, все так классно работает. Спасибо огромное. Я обязательно прочту о рекурсии.